# What does e/event property means in JS

Tags: javascript, events, dom

```
<script>
    var ohnoesEl = document.getElementById("ohnoes");
    var onOhNoesClick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
        audioEl.src = "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-sounds/rpg/giant-no.mp3";
        audioEl.autoplay = "true";
        document.body.appendChild(audioEl);
    };
    ohnoesEl.addEventListener("click", onOhNoesClick);
</script>
```

In this code, I didn't understand one thing. I checked internet and StackOverflow but couldn't find anything.

I have a problem to understand **event property**.

Why do we put **e** as an argument before we use properties such as `preventDefault`?

How will I realize whether I should use it or not?

Answer (score 1):

> **I have a problem to understand event property.**

Well, it's not a property. All event handling functions are automatically passed a reference to the **[`event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)** that represents the event currently being handled. This object can tell you quite a bit about the circumstances at the time of the event (i.e. which mouse button was clicked, what key was pressed, where on the screen the mouse was when the click happened, what object triggered the event, etc.).

> **Why do we put e as an argument before we use properties such as
>   preventDefault?**

The syntax of `e.preventDefault()` is simply common Object-Oriented Programming syntax of: `Object.method()`. We are accessing the `Event` object that was passed into the function with the `e` identifier and then invoking the `preventDefault` method stored within that object.

It's how you get at some object-specific behavior. `.preventDefault()` is not a global function, you can't just call it on its own. It's only something that an `event` object can do, so you have to reference the object before calling the method.

As with all function arguments, you may call the argument any valid name you like, but since the object will be an event object, `e`, `evt`, and `event` are quite common.

> **How will I realize whether I should use it or not?**

In your code: **[`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)**, indicates that the event that was triggered should not perform its built-in action, effectively cancelling the event.

You would use this technique in situations where the user has initiated some event, but your code determines that the process should not continue. The best example is with a form's `submit` event. If the user hasn't filled out all the required fields and then hits the `submit` button, we don't want the form to be submitted, so we check to see if the required fields were filled in and, if not, we cancel the `submit` event.

Here's an example:

```js
// Get a reference to the link:
var link = document.getElementById("nasaLink");

// Set up a click event callback function that will automatically
// be passed a reference to the click event when it occurs. In this
// example, the event will be received as "evt".
link.addEventListener("click", function(evt){ 
  console.clear(); // Cancel previous log entries

  // Get the type of event that was received and the object that triggered it
  console.log("You triggered a " + evt.type + " on :", evt.target)
  
  // Cancelling an event is generally based on some condition
  // Here, we'll make it simple and say that if you click on the 
  // link when the second is an even second, the navigation will be cancelled
  if(new Date().getSeconds() % 2 === 0){
  
    // Normally, clicking a valid hyperlink will navigate you away from the current page
    // But, we'll cancel that native behavior by cancelling the event:
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(evt.type + " cancelled! No navigation will occur."); 
  }
  
  console.log("The mouse was postioned at: " + evt.screenX + " x " + evt.screenY);
  
  console.log("The SHIFT key was pressed at the time? " + evt.shiftKey);
  console.log("\tTry clicking again, but with SHIFT held down this time.");
});
```

```html
<a href="http://www.nasa.gov" id="nasaLink" target="_blank">Click for NASA</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **event** property is an object that is passed to every event handler.

This **event** object then has many properties and methods you can call to manipulate the event process and action in the handler.

For instance, in the **event** object you have this method called `preventDefault()` . What does `preventDefault()` do? Each event is triggered by a particular html dom element in the page. Sometimes this html elements have behaviour attached to them. For instance, and `<a>` element has the potential of changing the browser url for a particular window. If the element that triggered the event is then an `<a>`, with `preventDefault()` you just cut the default behaviour for that `<a>` anchor and that will avoid an url load/change.

I recommend you find a reference for this `event` object and pay a read to it. So you'll become more familiar to what it is available within it.